# Bibliography behavior not consistent

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, apa-style

I'm wondering why my bibliography doesn't print the publisher of one of my entries.
As you can see in the picture, the first and last entry are both books, but the second one doesn't show the publisher, even though it's in the `*.bib` file.
[image: Weird acting bibliography]

Here are my document settings:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%...
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
natbib=true,
style=apa,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false,
eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{MyBibExample}
%...
\begin{document}
\citep{Helber2014}
\citep{Ritzman1979}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and my `bib` file looks like this:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Book{Helber2014,
  title     = {Operations Management Tutorial},
  publisher = {Helber, Hildesheim},
  year      = {2014},
  author    = {Stefan Helber},
  isbn      = {9783000469183},
}

@Book{Ritzman1979,
  title     = {Disaggregation},
  publisher = {Springer Netherlands},
  year      = {1979},
  editor    = {Larry P. Ritzman and Lee J. Krajewski and William L. Berry and Stephen H. Goodman and Stanley T. Hardy and Lawrence D. Vitt},
  address   = {Dordrecht},
  isbn      = {978-94-015-7638-3},
  doi       = {10.1007/978-94-015-7636-9},
  ean       = {9789401576383},
  pagetotal = {724},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType: bibtex;}
```

There are more books in this file and they all display correctly ...
Am I missing something?
Thanks for your help!

PS: I'm running PdfLaTeX+Bib(la)tex+PdfLaTeX(2x) and my Bib(la)tex is set to `biber %`
PPS: using TeXMaker 5.0.3 with MiKTeX 2.9

Comment: Are you using pdflatex? xelatex?

Comment: Please make sure your example actually runs as it should, `Ritzman1979` is cited with two `n`'s in the body. Other than that, I agree this looks very strange.

Comment: sry, fixed that typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to continue to delete irrelevant stuff until you have only what is needed to show the bug, to know where the problem is.

I got to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa,doi=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{doi.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with `doi.bib` having

```
@Book{withdoi,
  title     = {Title},
  year      = 2019,                   
  publisher = {Publisher},
  author    = {Author},                   
  doi     = {10.1007/978-94-015-7636-9},
}
@Book{withoutdoi,
  title     = {Title},
  year      = 2019,                   
  publisher = {Publisher},
  author    = {Author},                   
}
```

This produces:

```
Author. (2019a). Title.
Author. (2019b). Title. Publisher.
```

I couldn't remove the style `apa` and still get the problem. It turns out there is code in `apa.bbx` which implements this APA rule:

```
% (APA 7.02) No LOCATION/PUBLISHER if there is a DOI
%            (Inconsistent in 2nd printing, see 7.04:39 which
%            is incorrect in 2nd printing)
```

There it tests if the `doi` field is defined or not and only prints location+publisher if it is not. You can change that back by putting this in your document:

```
\newbibmacro*{location+publisher}{%
   \printlist[default][1-1]{location}%
   \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
   \printlist{publisher}%
   \newunit}
```

(This can be seen as a bug in `apa.bbx`. Then it should have a test that tests *also* if `doi=false` is given. Or you could argue that you never should set doi to false with the apa style.)

Comment: Thx @pst that explains a lot! I don't wan to start deleting stuff from my `*.bib` since I'm using the entries across multiple projects, but in this case I don't want to have the DOI printed. I'll try your solution with the `\newbibmacro*{}` and maybe also other bibliography styles...

Comment: I didn't mean for you to delete stuff from your real bib file! Just to delete more stuff for the test case, because only then was it clear where the problem was. (The document in your question had a lot of stuff that *could* have been relevant to the problem, but wasn't.)